# difference of HttpClient singleton instance or not

Tags: java, post, singleton, httpclient, instance

As HttpClient document suggests - Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application.

I got different behaviours between HttpClient is singleton or not.

1) With singleton, I first created a global static HttpClient instance, and send every request with this instance with below segment,

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
int status = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

2) Without singleton, I send every request by creating a new HttpClient instance

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
int status = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

The differences are, without singleton, everything is OK, I can get the correct result separately in consecutive requests. But with singleton, it seems there is some request context, the second request doesn't return the response string as expected because of the first request parameter (weird!!).

I don't have the service codes and server configuration. Can you help me figure out the possible reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get a chance to read this [page](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html)

Comment: What was the solution? I remember someone mentioned you got to close the HttpResponse object if you use singleton. Was this the issue?